# Saving complete Email (Body+Attachments) from Outlook to Sharepoint using Powerautomate

Tags: sharepoint, automation, outlook, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to save the complete emails (body and attachments) from outlook to sharepoint. My Power Automate flow is below that saves a .msg file but I also tried .eml. I am seeing files being saved to sharepoint but when I open it I see blanks(no body and no attachments). What would I need to change in my flow?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop the email attachments in order to get them exported as well.

Sudarshan wrote a very nice blog article demonstrating how to do this to OneDrive, but you can easily adapt this for SharePoint.  Refer to his article here for step by step instructions.
https://spknowledge.com/2021/03/19/power-automate-export-email-attachments-to-onedrive/